# Generate string-formatted Excel cell ranges from array?

Tags: xlsxwriter

I'm trying to use xlsx writer to, programmatically:

1. Insert a dataset into an excel sheet
2. Insert associated uncertainty data ("noise"), with same domain as dataset, into the sheet
3. Create a Excel scatter chart that has custom error bars, pointing to the noise data in (2) to use as both high and low error values

I've found that the error_bar properties (plus_values, minus_values) do not recognize the array format for cell ranges ['sheet name', start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col] used elsewhere in xlsx writer.

Is there a way to leverage the conversion function for array -> string format that must already exist in the module? (E.g. `xlsxwriter.cell_range(['data', 1,2,252,2])` returns the string `"='data'!$D$2:$D$253"`)

Alternatively, is this a common enough situation that custom error bar feature could be updated to support array as well as string-formatted cell ranges?

Kindly see example code below.

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('err_bar_test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

x_axis = np.arange(0,8*np.pi,0.1)
y_axis = np.sin(x_axis)
noise = np.random.random_sample(len(x_axis))


df = pd.DataFrame({'axis' : x_axis,
                   'value': y_axis,
                   'std_dev' : noise,
                  } )

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['data']


chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
worksheet.insert_chart('F2', chart)
chart.add_series({ 
    'values': ['data', 1,2,252,2],
    'categories': ['data', 1,1,252,1],
    'y_error_bars':{
        'type': 'custom',

# This works
        'plus_values': "='data'!$D$2:$D$253",
        'minus_values': "='data'!$D$2:$D$253",

# This does not work :(
#         'plus_values': ['data',1,3,252,3],
#         'minus_values': ['data',1,3,252,3],

                 },
    'smooth': 'true',
})

writer.save()
```